# Python install module and import

Tags: python-2.7, pywin32, pywinauto, pywin

I need to import win32wnet in my script.
However, the pywin module does not guaranteed to be installed on the machine the script is running.

So, in the same *.py script I installed the pywin before the import win32wnet.
But, that seems like not working.

Is there a way I can handle the install of pywin and import of win32wnet in the same script?

Or I have to separate the installation to another script and run ahead of the script dependence on win32wnet?(Or does that even work as I assumed?)

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand how this question is related to pywinauto, but I see you're interested in MS UI Automation topic. It's worth noting that just released [pywinauto 0.6.0](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/releases/tag/0.6.0) supports MS UI Automation under the hood (in pure Python, no compilation, no .NET).